# how to hide a canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I hide the canvas element? meaning that when I run the code there's nothing there then I can make it reappear with a button or something. Hopefully hide it in CSS but I can make javascript work too. Thanks! I know the javascript is messy, I put two files together because I can put js files in one snippet.

```js
var blob;


var blobs = [];
var zoom = 1;


function setup() {
    createCanvas(1000 , 700);
  blob = new Blob(0, 0, 21);
  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    var x = random(-width, width);
    var y = random(-height, height);
    blobs[i] = new Blob(x, y, 2);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  var newzoom = 40 / blob.r;
  zoom = lerp(zoom, newzoom, 0.05);
  scale(zoom);
  translate(-blob.pos.x, -blob.pos.y);

  for (var i = blobs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    blobs[i].show();
    if (blob.eats(blobs[i])) {
      blobs.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  blob.show();
  blob.update();
}
  
function Blob(x, y, r) {
  this.pos = createVector(x, y);
  this.r = r;
  this.vel = createVector(0, 0);

  this.update = function() {
    var newvel = createVector(mouseX - width / 2, mouseY - height / 2);
    newvel.setMag(3);
    this.vel.lerp(newvel, 0.2);
    this.pos.add(this.vel);
  };

  this.eats = function(other) {
    var d = p5.Vector.dist(this.pos, other.pos);
    if (d < this.r + other.r) {
      var sum = PI * this.r * this.r + PI * other.r * other.r;
      this.r = sqrt(sum / PI);
      //this.r += other.r;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  this.show = function() {
    fill(355);
    ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.r * 2, this.r * 2);
  };
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.4/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is created in memory so I don't think you can use css to hide it. You'll have to use JavaScript.

Comment: There is a `createCanvas` function that is referenced but is not provided. The reference to the canvas you can just set the height and width to zero.

Comment: `createCanvas` may inject some html that you could in theory update with a CSS class.